# Accuracy in neural network for regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, accuracy

I want to measure the accuracy in neural network that performs regression. I have two outputs. Is the root-mean-square deviation (
[RMS wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation)) the right way to go?

From wikipedia

> RMSD is a good measure of accuracy[...]

How do I use it? I want to show how the accuracy is changing over epochs.

In classification measuring accuracy is simple.
$$ accuracy = \frac{TP+FN}{TP+FP+TN+FN} $$

Comment: you can set the answer as the correct one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiples measures. You need to understand the nature of your data/regression you are using.

#### For example:

**MAPE** is a pretty good measure for time series data, but will not work if has zero in the data or in the regression.

The most used **RMSE** and **MSE** are used to minimize the error, not necessarily the accuracy. The most close to zero better the measure.

#### For next step:

It's good to use measures that will automatically compare you model with other models, so you will be able to tell if your model is better than guessing or random walk models.

For instance:

#### Theil’s U

> Theil’s U statistic is a relative accuracy measure that compares the
> forecasted results with the results of forecasting with minimal historical
> data. It also squares the deviations to give more weight to large errors and
> to exaggerate errors, which can help eliminate methods with large errors.

Comment: Thank you for the MAPE direction. I went for R squared to track how well I fit my data.

Comment: @jumalo  Good! I just updated my answer, with more examples of measures You can look up.

Comment: @jumalo please mark as correct answer

Comment: @jumalo As a heads up, R$^2$ does not have the usual "percent of variation explained" interpretation when the model is nonlinear (neural nets are nonlinear).